# change bytes[] to string

Tags: java, android

I have a problem in this code
The `tv.setText(str);` is working and the text for `tv` change to `"LED1"`, but in `if(str=="LED1")` it's not working! What is the problem?

```
Handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    { 
        byte [] data= (byte[]) msg.obj;
        try {
            tv.setText("");
            String str = new String(data, "UTF-8");
            tv.setText(str);
            if(str=="LED1")
            {
                tv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `equals` instead of `==` for a `String`.

Which mean `if(str.equals("LED1"))` instead of `if(str=="LED1")`

See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The issue occurs because you are using `==` operators to compare to strings. You need to use `equals` to match the string. As we require to compare the values.

change the below line

```
if(str=="LED1")
```

to

```
if("LED1".equals(str))
```